# Macbook shows question mark folder on boot, can't boot to recovery mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, recovery

Recently I upgraded from Mojave to Catalina and I decided to encrypt my macbook's SSD, and also its firmware (it showed a long password after encryption and I wrote it down).

After Installation I realized one of my corporate softwares doesn't work and I decided to downgrade to Mojave again.

So I tried to use Startup Disk (in system preferences) to load from Mojave's bootable USB stick, but it didn't show up in there.

So I decided to enter recovery mode, but key combinations didn't worked.

Then I used terminal to force entering recovery mode, I executed:

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
sudo reboot
```

Finally I entered the recovery mode!

I deleted Catalina's both partitions on SSD to install Mojave, then accidentally took off my usb stick, after connecting it again, recovery mode wasn't able to run from usb stick.

I rebooted the macbook, and it now shows a folder with question mark which means can't read from bootable disk.

All I can do now is powering on and off the macbook. Can't reset nvram, can't reset pram, can't reset SMC, can't boot into recovery mode. All key combinations fail to work just after Catalina installation. I tried using an USB keyboard but that didn't worked too.

Also it's impossible to send macbook to apple for service as I live in overseas and there is no way for me to send it for service.

It's my work laptop, what should I do?

If you know how to reinstall macOS, boot to recovery or even boot from USB stick (to load macOS installation or linux/windows), please help me.

System: Macbook Air 13" (early 2014)
Available bootable USB sticks: Mojave, Catalina, Ubuntu, CentOS, Windows 10.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314, "If you can't start up from macOS Recovery": Does this still work?

Comment: @nohillside I can turn macbook on and it shows a blinking screen with a question mark on a folder so I believe it still works, but no key combination works on startup since installation of Catalina (I tried all known key combinations including Internet Recovery Mode). I don't know, but maybe Catalina has deleted/disabled some hidden part of disk which were related to processing these key combinations? And now that I deleted partitions on disk, it can't load the macOS too?